# Check package dependencies

Tags: migration-tool

I'd like to run a sf:deploy in an org we're using for continuous integration.  My package is dependent on a couple other packages which are updated semi-frequently.  I've been using autoUpdatePackage="true" in the related deploy target and the .installedPackage metadata.

The trouble is that it seems to always update the package to that version even when it's not needed.  This can add a significant amount of unnecessary time to the build.  Is there any way to make it "smart" to only update if needed?

Current script below:

```
    <target name="deployDependencies">
    <sf:deploy autoUpdatePackage="true" deployRoot="${sf.dependencyRepository}" 
        ignoreWarnings="true" logType="Detail" maxPoll="999"
        password="${sf.password}${sf.token}" rollbackOnError="true" 
        serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" singlepackage="true" testLevel="NoTestRun" 
        trace="false" username="${sf.username}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: AFAIK there isn't anything off the shelf. We had the same problem, and in the end wrote our own Ant task that retrieves the version information (using the metadata API and only installs (using the metadata API) where necessary. The version checking takes quite a few seconds but is a lot quicker than the install time. Unfortunately this isn't open source today.